# prevent BeautifulSoup's find_all() from converting escaped html tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, escaping

I have some text:

`text = <p>&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;<br/></p>`

That I read with [beautiful soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

`soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser") # soup: <p>&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;<br/></p>`

Then I want to get text nodes:

`text_nodes = soup.find_all(text=True)`

But the escaped HTML gets unescaped in the process: `text_nodes: ['<b>test</b>']`

How do I prevent `find_all()` step from converting my escaped HTML tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `text=True` I think there is no option to keep the string as is.

my solution is just escape the result with loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import escape

text = '<p>&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;<br/></p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
text_nodes = [escape(x) for x in soup.strings]
print(text_nodes)
# ['&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;']
```

`soup.strings`is shorter version of `soup.find_all(text=True)`.

Comment: What happens to the <br/> in your case, won't it get escaped too though?

Comment: `<br>` like `<p>` is a `tag` not text.

Comment: so it won't  get escaped.

Comment: Thanks!  Problem though.... this doesn't actually give me a node, it just gives me the text content of the node.  I need the bs4 node so I can manipulate it and do bs4 things.